# How to receive bundle when navigating with Mvvmcross 5.x

Tags: c#, navigation, mvvmcross

I'm a complete newbie to Android programming. 
I've chosen MvvmCross 5.x as my framework. 
I think I understand how to *send* both a 'complex' object *and* a dictionary (bundle) from a `ViewModel`:

```
Task Navigate<TParameter>(IMvxViewModel<TParameter> viewModel,
                          TParameter param, 
                          IMvxBundle presentationBundle = null);
```

How do I *receive* the bundle in the `ViewModel` being navigated to?
That is, what method is called with the dictionary/bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `presentationBundle` parameter you used for navigation is part of the `ViewModelRequest` object, which is passed to the `Show` method of your `MvxViewPresenter`. You can create a custom implementation of a view presenter on your platform and use the `PresentationBundle` to customize for example how the navigation transition looks or perhaps to modify the navigation stack.

See the `ViewModelRequest` source code [on GitHub](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/dc04dcc932a9702f2cd3cf94170477286a63448d/MvvmCross/Core/ViewModels/MvxViewModelRequest.cs). The property `PresentationValues` will contain the bundle you passed in the navigation. Following is an example implementation of custom view presenter on Android:

```cs
class CustomViewPresenter : MvxAndroidViewPresenter
{
    public CustomViewPresenter(IEnumerable<Assembly> androidViewAssemblies)
              : base(androidViewAssemblies)
    {
    }

    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        if (request.PresentationValues.ContainsKey("something"))
        {
            //handle presentation value
        }
        base.Show(request);
    }
}
```

There are more methods you can override in the presenter that use `ViewModelRequest` and where you can then access the `PresentationValues` property. These are specific for each platform and depend on the type of navigation being performed. On Android you have `ShowActivity`, `ShowDialogFragment`, `ShowFragment`, etc. You can see the default implementation of `MvxAndroidViewPresenter` on [MvvmCross Github](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/e85b2d07a18170838f83473d58b697599a456834/MvvmCross/Platform/Android/Views/MvxAndroidViewPresenter.cs) as well.

You can see a nice example of how a custom `ViewPresenter` with `PresentationBundle` can be used in [this blog post](https://gregshackles.com/presenters-in-mvvmcross-using-presentation-values/) by the awesome Greg Shackles. He also has a [nice introduction](https://gregshackles.com/presenters-in-mvvmcross-a-primer/) to view presenters.

Comment: For other newbies making the same mistake I did:

Comment: If the answer solved your question, please consider marking it as solution by clicking the grey checkmark :-)

Comment: Hi Martin,  I apologize for the lack of etiquette.  Getting used to SO.  You completely changed my understanding of the 'bundle' parameter.  Now I know how to use it.  Thanx, M.

Comment: No problem at all :-) ! Glad it helped :-). Wish you happy coding!